# Multiple frames / user input(visibility)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a main frame with a bunch of buttons. Each of which will create additional frames and more frames spawned from there.
BUT: When ever a frame is created and set visible, all frames created and displayed before should not be selectable, but still visible (i.e. No user input should be possible there). How can I prevent activity in older frames till the latest frame is disposed off? How can I restore focus for the previous frames afterwards?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  And yes, this would call for a modal dialog or `JOptionPane` as mentioned by JB Nizet.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called a modal dialog box. Checkout [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) and the [swing tutorial about dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: I am not sure I see how to solve my problem. Will keep exploring. Will post when I do have some solution.